# Command line Logs in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, adb

I'm using Android Studio to build an Android app. Is there a windows to show up which adb command lines the Android Studio are currently using? For example, when the Android Studio is launching the app to the device or the emulator, the windows will show up the adb commands to launch the app.

I notice that there is an "ADB logs" windows which show the logs, but I hope to see the command lines that AS is calling.

Thanks!

Comment: Hope, I don't think it is possible while being inside of android studio. However you can issue adb commands from the terminal tab below in your   Android Studio app. While building a project you can check the gradle console, adb logs for more details. Oterwise, install your project.apk from the Terminal tab in your Android Studio app using **adb -d install /your_apk_path/project.apk** command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the way to inspect the adb commands. When launching the app, we can inspect those commands in the `Run` tap at the bottom of the Android Studio, though these commands are mixed with some other logs.